# override paint method of textarea in scala swing

Tags: swing, scala, overriding, paint

I'm  learning scala.swing currently and i was curious if I could override a paint method of an existing component like textarea, turns out yes I can but then again I think that I'm doing something wrong:

```
var rectangles = List[Rectangles]()

val textarea = new TextArea(){
    override def paint(g:Graphics2D){
        super.paint(g)
        rectangles.foreach{g.draw}
    }
}
```

This snippet shows that i have a list of rectangles and a textarea. This is not supposed to make sense. I was just curious if I could manage to draw rectangles on a textarea.

When debugging/adding prints it clearly shows me that it runs through my overridden paint method yet it wont show my rectangles

Am I simply using the Graphics2D object wrong or why is it that I cant see my rectangles?

thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 0):

ok it turns out that I cant use the foreach like this, this it how it works

```
rectangles.foreach{r => g.draw(r)}
```

this answers the actual question yet it leaves me confused since I am used to use foreach like this

```
foo.foreach{println}
```

but thats another question I guess

Comment: you definitely can use foreach in the way mentioned in question. plz add more info. (is rectangles list empty? for instance)

Comment: rectangles is not empty -> whether it works or not seems to only depend on the way i use the foreach

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as expected.

```
import scala.swing._

object Test extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  var rectangles = List[Rectangle]()

  val textarea = new TextArea(){
    override def paint(g:Graphics2D){
      super.paint(g)
      rectangles.foreach{g.draw}
    }
  }

  lazy val top = new Frame {
    rectangles ::= new Rectangle(8, 8, 20, 20) // example
    contents = textarea
    size = new Dimension(100, 100)
  }
}

Test.main(null)
```